# How to disable payment method for manually created order

Tags: magento

I have magneto store.it is working fine.we are taking payment online when some one placed orders.We are also placing order manually from the admin.We don't want to take payment when place order manually.
So we want to disable payment method for manually placed order.

Comment: are the orders you're taking in Admin free then? You can turn on other payment options for Admin to take.. IE Check or PO. and if in the Admin the CSR uses that it will put order into pending status for invoicing.

Comment: But when customer place order online we only want to show one payment method.

Comment: How are you getting paid when entering the orders in Admin?

Comment: I would turn on something like PO and then hide the PO on the frontend as an option in app>design>YOUR_PACKAGE>Your_Theme>template>checkout>onepage>payment>methods.phtml

Comment: Can you me exact code what i need to put in methods.phtml

Comment: maybe the easier thing for you would be create coupon for your CSR to enter that would discount the entire order including shipping to free and when the CSR enters an order and the coupon code it will take it. It will put order into pending status and from there you can invoice the order which in turn will change status to complete. If you are not using Magento as an ERP you would be ok. I will fix some code for the other method and post here when i get it done.